# Scheduling software to schedule several people into different timeslots

Tags: calendar, scheduling, outlook, office, office365

Our company uses Office 365 and we have about 30 employees.
Office days are from tuesday 8-5 and thursday 8-5.
I need to have an individual meeting with each and every employee for about 30 minutes.

All employees obviously have their own schedules so they would need to be able to pick a spot somewhere in the office days.

I'm looking for a piece of software to assist with this. Would be great if this had some kind of outlook integration as well.

I'm imagining the process as follows:

1. I pick out timeslots, like every thursday and friday for a month from 8-5.
2. I sent out 30 emails to 30 employees
3. They can click a link and schedule a meeting somewhere into the time slots

Note: In outlook i can schedule multiple people for one meething, but not schedule a bunch of people for a bunch of meetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calendy](https://calendly.com/features) can accomplish what you're looking for. It allows you send out available times and handles the scheduling for you.

Comment: I just schedulded some meetings with Calendy - works great. Has a pretty sweet interface i was pretty impressed. Also integrated with outlook pretty nicely.